# Approval sent to myself for testing. Clicking to approve takes me to flows.microsoft.com to the list of approvals sent/received etc?

Tags: power-automate

An approval sent to myself for testing. Clicking to approve takes me to flows.microsoft.com to the list of approvals sent/received etc?
Why is this happening?
Power automate is a good idea but the implementation needs a lot of improvements.

Comment: Where are you clicking to "Approve", outlook email or Teams or somewhere else?

Comment: That is in Outlook Desktop

Answer (score 0):

If clicking Approve brings you to flow.microsoft.com, it could be your email client does not support Actionable Messages. [Click this link to see which email client is supported for it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/#outlook-version-requirements-for-actionable-messages).

https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/pt-pt/blog/actionable-messages-approvals/

Comment: I am not sure what is going on but this worked in my previous attempts to set this workflow so the client is definitely compatible. It is true that before the approve/reject button was a plain black and white one. Now it is a colored button, blue fill. Why did the format change?

Comment: What is your email client/app and what device? Make sure it's the recommended client. If yes, try clearing the cache (or reset in Windows 10), uninstall & reinstall app. It's a very rare case but I do face actionable messages failed to render once, but rarely happen. What I did was to close the Outlook and reopen.

Comment: You can try this link https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/ (the new version is https://amdesigner.azurewebsites.net/) to see if Actionable Message works well in your client by sending yourself an email with it.

Comment: the client is Outlook Desktop as mentioned  in one of the comments -no cache there AFAIK

Comment: Which version of Desktop? Have you tried Outlook web version?

Comment: I need this to work with Outlook desktop.
Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2112 Build 16.0.14729.20312) 64-bit

Comment: Then it's time for you to raise MS Ticket Support from inside your Office 365. If it's a genuine issue, they might need to look at it. Mention keyword like "Actionable Messages" and "Flow" in the ticket description.